# Usar dados database mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Esse código funciona corretamente com as datas fixas. Como fazer para usar as datas que estão cadastradas no banco de dados mysql?

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['year']) && !empty($_REQUEST['month'])) {
$dates = array(
    array(
        'date' => '2016-09-17',
        'badge' => false,
        'title' => 'Evento para o dia 22-09-17',
        'body' => 'Descrição do evento',
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2016-09-23',
        'badge' => false,
        'title' => 'Evento para o dia 22-09-23',
        'body' => 'Descrição do evento',
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2016-09-30',
        'badge' => false,
        'title' => 'Evento para o dia 22-09-30',
        'body' => 'Descrição do evento',
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2016-10-02',
        'badge' => false,
        'title' => 'Evento para o dia 22-10-02',
        'body' => 'Descrição do evento',
    ),
);
echo json_encode($dates); } else { echo json_encode(array()); }
```

Comment: o que vc já tentou? Um select * from tabela e algum loop por exemplo?

Comment: Consegui resolver.

Comment: @DiegoRibeirodaSilva Poste vc mesmo a reposta.

Comment: Ja editei e coloquei a resposta.

Comment: @DiegoRibeirodaSilva coloque a resposta como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver assim.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','usuario','senha_database','tabela_database');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM eventos")) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $dates[] = array(
                            'date' => $row['data'],
                            'badge' => false,
                            'title' => 'Evento para o dia' . $row['data'],
                            'body' => 'Descrição do evento',
                        );
    }
    echo json_encode($dates);
}
```